# How is it famous action actors are able to do the workouts they do for a role?

Tags: training

So you always hear about famous actors who work out for a specific role. The one that came to mind for me, as I was writing this question, was Hugh Jackman who said many times in interviews that he worked out 3 hours per day, 6 days a week for his role as Wolverine.

Obviously, I get why famous rich people have it easier to get ripped. Personal chefs, personal trainers, this is their job, etc. But one thing I never understood is, why are these people able to workout like this without over training? No matter who they are, they are only human, in human bodies. There always comes a point where someone over trains, and it is detrimental to fitness, or so I've been told. So what is it that makes these famous peoples' workout regimens seem immune to this?

I feel like, if I asked any personal trainer or healthcare professional: "Hey, can I workout 3 hours per day for 6 days a week?" They would absolutely say no, don't do that. Assuming I kept my nutrition in check, COULD I do this?

Comment: Don't forget that everything you hear from Hollywood isn't 100% true. And also keep in mind that actors will use steroids and other performance enhancing drugs to get results in the amount of time that they have.

Comment: @Bert I know not everything from Hollywood is true, but I can't imagine why actors would lie about their workout routines for movies. There wouldn't really be any benefit in that. Although, I wouldn't be too surprised if they took steroids or the like.

Comment: For Hugh Jackman specifically it's not like it happened over night, take a look at him in X-Men 1 which came out in 2000. Still in good shape back then but compared to what's probably his peek in Days of Future Past (2014) not even close. He's had over a decade to get to that level and hasn't really taken much of a break in that time.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/26-doug--s-6-day-cutting-routine.html) is an example of a six-day a week workout (I found it by Googling "six day workout plan").  Some things to note:

1. The actual weightlifting is only about an hour a day.  Perhaps as much as 75 minutes.
2. Two hours a day of the workout is cardio, and light cardio at that.
3. Stretches (before and after workout) are included in the three hours a day.
4. It divides the body into three areas (chest and triceps; back and biceps; legs and shoulders).  Each area is only exercised twice a week.

They don't mention it, but this is not the kind of workout you start on your first day.  You would initially start with a more normal workout, two or three days a week.  You would work up to this kind of workout over time.  Even just the twelve hours a week of light cardio is something that you'd work to over time.

I don't know where you are in your workout regimen now.  But you shouldn't assume that the only thing between you and this workout is nutrition.  You should be able to do the twelve hours of light cardio (don't forget to stretch) comfortably before you even think about the lifting portion.  Also, don't go straight from two or three days to six.  [Four](https://www.muscleandfitness.com/training/build-muscle/4-week-beginners-workout-guide-getting-big) and [five-day](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/what-is-the-best-5-day-workout-split.html) workouts can serve as useful transitions (again, links from Google).  Note that they divide the body differently than the six-day workout.

I can't emphasize this enough.  This is an intense workout regimen.  It's not something that you start doing tomorrow because it sounds cool.  It's something that you work your way up to doing.

And don't forget to stretch and do warm up and cool down cardio.  They may feel like fluff, but they are part of what keeps your blood flowing and clearing out the toxins from overusing your muscles.  At this level of workout, stretches and cardio are mandatory, not optional.  And as you say, good nutrition and plenty of water.  You need a whole life plan, not just a weightlifting plan.

Comment: I mean, thanks, but none of this information has anything to directly do with my question, which is specifically about how Hollywood actors can train in this manner (e.g. 3 hrs/day 6 days/week) without over training. It's just general information about 4/5/6 day workout splits. Also, for your second point, as an example, Henry Cavill has said he does NO cardio for his role as Superman, since his character specifically needs to be BIG.

Comment: Hollywood actors do it the same as everyone else, by changing the exercise areas so that they only train a particular muscle two or three times a week.  [Cavill's workout](https://www.popworkouts.com/superman-workout/) is shorter (only an hour a day) and still includes some cardio, more than two hours of his six hours a week.